# How to plot inequalities

Tags: matlab

I would like to plot the following inequalities:
*y* < *p*<sub>2</sub>(1 - *p*<sub>1</sub>) and *x* < *p*<sub>1</sub>(1 - ( y / (1 - *p*<sub>1</sub>))).

Given that the first is satisfied, I want to plot the region in which both are satisfied.
*p*<sub>1</sub> and *p*<sub>2</sub> can vary within [0,1].

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this: The red area is where both inequalities are satisfied.

```
[X,Y]=meshgrid(0:0.01:1,0:0.01:1); % Make a grid of points between 0 and 1
p1=0.1; p2=0.2; % Choose some parameters
ineq1 = Y<p2*(1-p1);
ineq2 = X<p1*(1-(Y./(1-p1)));
colors = zeros(size(X))+ineq1+ineq2;
scatter(X(:),Y(:),3,colors(:),'filled')
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to explain the "magic" behind the `colors = ...` line.

Comment: The explanation for the colors is that each inequation is actually a binary matrix of 0's and 1's indicating where it is satisfied and where it is not. `colors` is their sum, and equals 2 where both inequations are satisfied, 1 where only one of them is, and 0 where none are. `scatter` assigns a different color for each value, and `2` gets the red color (in the default colormap red is assigned to the maximal value).

Answer (score 10):

An alternative solution (yet similar to Sam Robert's) would be using [`contourf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/contourf.html):

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid((0:999) / 1000, (0:999) / 1000);
p = rand(2, 1);                            %# In this example p = [0.1, 0.2]
ineq1 = Y < p(2) * (1 - p(1));             %# First inequation
ineq2 = X < p(1) * (1 - (Y / (1 - p(1)))); %# Second inequation
both = ineq1 & ineq2;                      %# Intersection of both inequations

figure, hold on
c = 1:3;                                   %# Contour levels
contourf(c(1) * ineq1, [c(1), c(1)], 'b')  %# Fill area for first inequation
contourf(c(2) * ineq2, [c(2), c(2)], 'g')  %# Fill area for second inequation
contourf(c(3) * both, [c(3), c(3)], 'r')   %# Fill area for both inequations
legend('First', 'Second', 'Both')
set(gca, ...                               %# Fixing axes ticks
    'XTickLabel', {t(get(gca, 'XTick'))}, 'YTickLabel', {t(get(gca, 'YTick'))})
```

and this is the result:

[image: Result]

The red area (as mentioned in the legend) indicates where both inequations are satisfied.

Note that the second and third `contourf` calls are just for illustration, to show where only one of the inequations is satisfied.

Comment: This solution didn't work for anything but your inequation. What is the meaning of meshgrid parameters? How to make it fit my inequations, whatever they are?

Comment: @TomášZato Perhaps you didn't employ my solution properly. The meshgrid is supposed to create a two-dimensional matrix of X and Y values as an input for the inequalities.

Comment: Yes, I surelly didn't use your solution properly. With [my equations](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3C%3D30%2B5y%2C+x%3C%3D0), all I could see was blank graph. When I edited the meshgrid to `meshgrid((-100:100) , (-100:100));` I could see nice plot as yours but [with messed up axes markers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TZGyl.png).

Comment: @TomášZato I think you get an empty graph because the `meshgrid` in my example yields only positive coordinates, whereas your inequalities are satisfied by negative values. I can only speculate that you get "messed up" markers because your inequalities aren't implemented/normalized properly (you didn't share your implementation, so I cannot say where it went wrong).

Comment: What is _t_ ? MATLAB says: Undefined function or variable 't'

Comment: @DavidBalažic You're right, the line that defines `t` is missing. It is used to adjust the tick labels, and it is supposed to be the same vector that built `X` and `Y`. In this example `t = (0:999) / 100`. You can also comment out the last statement if it bothers you.

Answer (score 3):

I think this method is easy to understand. Make a surface plot and rotate it to top view.

```
v = -5:0.1:5;
p1 = 0.1;
p2 = 0.2;
[x,y] = meshgrid(v);
ineq1 = y<p2*(1-p1);
ineq2 = x<p1*(1-(y./(1-p1)));
ineq = double(ineq1 & ineq2);    % intersection of the inequalities
surf(x,y,ineq);
view(0,90)      % rotate surface plot to top view
```