# How to draw solutions to an inequality in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to plot 3d inequalities on matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476447/how-to-plot-3d-inequalities-on-matlab)

I have a problem drawing the solutions to the following inequality

```
S(c,delta,xT)-S(2,1,1)>=0

while 0<c<4, 1<delta<3, f(c,delta)<xT<1.
```

I would like a 3 dimensional plot showing which triples (c,delta,xT) satisfies this. I have tried using `isosurface`, but I seem to get only the solutions in equality.

**EDIT**

I have tried

```
[xT, delta, c] = meshgrid(0.8:.01:1, 1:.1:3, 0:.1:4);
values = calc.S0Func(2,1, 1)- calc.S0Func(c,delta, xT);            
patch(isosurface(c, delta, values, values, 0), 'FaceColor', 'red');
view(3);
```

But I only get a plot of the values satisfying the problem in equality. I would like to have all values satisfying the inequality.

Comment: have you tried meshgrid to enumerate the points?

Comment: there is no solution there either, evidently

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345838/how-to-plot-inequalities