# matlab - plot inequality in 3d with surf

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot

I want to plot an inequality in 3d using `surf`. My condition is

```
0<=x<=1    
0<=y<=1    
0<=z<=x/(1+y)
```

I can create a surface plot using the following commands

```
[x y]=meshgrid(0:0.01:1);    
z=x./(1+y);    
surf(x,y,z);
```

This plot gives me regions where `z=x/(1+y)` but I am interested in regions where `0<=z<=x/(1+y)` over all values of `x` and `y`. However, I am unable to plot/color the region explicitly. Can you please help.

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476447/how-to-plot-3d-inequalities-on-matlab) has been asked but there was no acceptable answer and my question is also different.

Answer (score 3):

Using `isosurface` you can show the boundary. There are two options, first create the points

```
[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(0:.01:1);
```

then plot the boundaries in the `z`-direction (i.e. `Z=0` and `Z=X./(1+Y)`)

```
isosurface(X,Y,Z,Z.*(X./(1+Y)-Z),0)
```

or plot all the boundaries (including `X=0`, `X=1`, `Y=0` and `Y=1`)

```
isosurface(X,Y,Z,Z.*(X./(1+Y)-Z).*X.*(X-1).*Y.*(Y-1),0)
```

All you have to do is come up with a function that is constant on any boundary, its value inside or outside is irrelevant as long as it is not zero.

Comment: Thanks. Can I interpret that any point inside this region means z<x/(1+y) and outside means z>x/(1+y)?