# matlab drawing graph. especially conditional graph like <=10

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to draw graph in matlab but I dont know how to program it in matlab. I am facing problems.

```
gone = -xone-xtwo+10<=0; 
gtwo = -2*xone+3*xtwo-10<=0
```

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345838/how-to-plot-inequalities

Answer (score 2):

You sound like you're new to matlab, so instead of trying to "program" the graph, why don't you try using the user interface provided?

Do the following:

1. In your workspace, right-click the variable you want to graph.
2. Click on plot catalog.
3. Choose the type of graph you want, then click plot.

Even better, if you want to see how to actually use code to build the plot that you now have, just go to the window where your plot was generated, and click File - Generate Code.