# How to plot Inequalities using (plot::Inequality) in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, inequality

I want to plot some Inequalities with matlab.
I am using this code:

```
figure;
plot(plot::Inequality(x^2 + y^2 < 1, x = -1.5..1.5, y = -1.5..1.5));
```

But i am getting this error:

```
plot(plot::Inequality(x^2 + y^2 < 1, x = -1.5..1.5, y = -1.5..1.5))
      |
Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

I have read this [manual](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/plot-inequality.html).
and something more:

```
>> version
ans =
8.0.0.783 (R2012b)
```

Comment: Related question to plotting inequalites: [How to plot inequalities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345838/how-to-plot-inequalities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plot::Inequality` is part of Matlab's symbolic toolbox and is invoked from within [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/getting-started-with-mupad.html).
You cannot use it like a regular command.